# svg animation background showing black in iOS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have added this svg animation to my website's homepage hero section:

```html
<div id="bg-wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
                <defs>
                <radialGradient id="Gradient1" cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="0.441602%" fy="50%" r=".5"><animate attributeName="fx" dur="34s" values="0%;3%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(255, 0, 255, 0)"></stop></radialGradient>
                <radialGradient id="Gradient2" cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="2.68147%" fy="50%" r=".5"><animate attributeName="fx" dur="23.5s" values="0%;3%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)"></stop></radialGradient>
                <radialGradient id="Gradient3" cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="0.836536%" fy="50%" r=".5"><animate attributeName="fx" dur="21.5s" values="0%;3%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)"></stop></radialGradient>
                <radialGradient id="Gradient4" cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="4.56417%" fy="50%" r=".5"><animate attributeName="fx" dur="23s" values="0%;5%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)"></stop></radialGradient>
                </defs>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient4)">
                <animate attributeName="x" dur="20s" values="25%;0%;25%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" dur="21s" values="0%;25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="17s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                </rect>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient5)">
                <animate attributeName="x" dur="23s" values="0%;-25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" dur="24s" values="25%;-25%;25%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                </rect>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient6)">
                <animate attributeName="x" dur="25s" values="-25%;0%;-25%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" dur="26s" values="0%;-25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 50 50" to="0 50 50" dur="19s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                </rect>
                <rect x="13.744%" y="1.18473%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient1)" transform="rotate(334.41 50 50)"><animate attributeName="x" dur="20s" values="25%;0%;25%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animate attributeName="y" dur="21s" values="0%;25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></rect>
                <rect x="-2.17916%" y="35.4267%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient2)" transform="rotate(255.072 50 50)"><animate attributeName="x" dur="23s" values="-25%;0%;-25%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animate attributeName="y" dur="24s" values="0%;50%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                </rect>
                <rect x="9.00483%" y="14.5733%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Gradient3)" transform="rotate(139.903 50 50)"><animate attributeName="x" dur="25s" values="0%;25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animate attributeName="y" dur="19s" values="0%;25%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 50 50" to="0 50 50" dur="9s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
                </rect>
                </svg>
</div>
```

This is looking fine on laptops and mobiles except for iOS. when I open my website on iOS then the SVG animation background is looking black except white while I have explicitly applied white background on the #bg-wrap div as well as on the body also.
This is how it's looking on iOS
[image]

Can Anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you define gradient5 and gradient6 somewhere else? Because you're using them as fills without defining them.

Comment: probably the body or the parent of the svg element has background: black (dark mode?). Try adding `<rect width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>` right after the defs

Comment: @enxaneta I have explicitly added white background on the body and parent of the SVG as well but still, the problem exists.

Comment: @enxaneta adding a new rect solved the problem.